# I need to fill a lambda query from an ICollection <int>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

It is the first time that I use linq and lambda functions. I'm using .NET core and EF core 3.0.

Eu preciso que a lista abaixo que será preenchida dinamicamente preencha a função lambda conforme segue:

```
            var years = new List<int>
            {
                2017,
                2018,
                2019
            };
```

I need to use the list above to fill in the Lambda function, as this list will be variable.

```
var result = _myRepository.Find(x=>x.reference == reference && x.year in (2017,2018,2019)))
```

my repository.

```
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var result = _DbSet.Where(predicate);

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to do `x.year in (2017,2018,2019)` in `Linq`? if yes then you can try `years.Any(y => y == x.year)`. If no, then please elaborate your question in **English**

Comment: you can use ``contains``your request : ``var result = _myRepository.Find(x=>x.reference == reference && yeas.Contains(x.year)))``

Comment: Hi @vrsfilho, any updates on your question? Did it answer your question.

Comment: I need the list of years to fill in the list where I marked with xxx so that this is dynamic.
var result = _myRepository.Find (x => x.reference == reference && x.year in (x, x, x)))

Answer (score 1):

you can use `contains` function to check the array of years contains the record year
as following:

```
var years = new List<int>
            {
                2017,
                2018,
                2019
            };

var result = _myRepository.Find(x=>x.reference == reference && years.AsEnumerable().Contains( x.year));
```

Comment: I've used it, but the EF core doesn't understand this query.

Comment: @vrsfilho what is the error you got

Comment: EF core 3.0 says it can't interpret the query @Ahmed

Comment: @vrsfilho It's a 3.0 bug, tracked by https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17342 and fixed in EF3.1 so you can update EF to 3.1 or try the updated solution as workaround

Comment: Ahmed Yousif Tks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it

```
    var years = new List<int> { 2017, 2018, 2019 };
    var _myRepository = new [] 
    { 
        new { year = 2017, reference = "123"},
        new { year = 2018, reference = "456"},
        new { year = 2019, reference = "789"}
    };
    var reference = "789";
    var result = _myRepository.Where(x =>x.reference == reference && years.Any(y => y == x.year));

    foreach(var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine(item.reference);
        // **Output**: "789"
```

Comment: After any ("years" does not appear in the equation)

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please take a look at @vrsfilho

Comment: I tried that too, but EF core 3.0 says it can't interpret the query